# Simplifiying IF statements

Tags: javascript

I've been studying javaScript for two weeks now and I know there must be a better wayf doing what is shown bellow.

This is what happens:
The function `myId()` call another function and receives back a parameter that can be mk-prod06, mk-prod05, mk-prod04, mk-prod03. But I was wondering if I can make this function more flexible by accepting any parameter (mk-prod0x) where x can be any number. I don't' want to hand write every "if" for it. Is that even possible in this case? Thank you.

```
//Hides and shows product boxes

function myId() {
    adjustStyle();
    var showProduct6, showProduct5, showProduct4, showProduct3, hideProduct6, hideProduct5, hideProduct4, hideProduct3;
    if (oProdId === "mk-prod06") {
        showProduct6 = document.getElementById("mk-prod06");
        showProduct5 = document.getElementById("mk-prod05");
        showProduct4 = document.getElementById("mk-prod04");
        showProduct3 = document.getElementById("mk-prod03");
        showProduct6.style.display = "inline";
        showProduct5.style.display = "inline";
        showProduct4.style.display = "inline";
        showProduct3.style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (oProdId === "mk-prod05") {
        hideProduct6 = document.getElementById("mk-prod06");
        hideProduct6.style.display = "none";
        showProduct5 = document.getElementById("mk-prod05");
        showProduct4 = document.getElementById("mk-prod04");
        showProduct3 = document.getElementById("mk-prod03");
        showProduct5.style.display = "inline";
        showProduct4.style.display = "inline";
        showProduct3.style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (oProdId === "mk-prod04") {
        hideProduct6 = document.getElementById("mk-prod06");
        hideProduct5 = document.getElementById("mk-prod05");
        hideProduct6.style.display = "none";
        hideProduct5.style.display = "none";
        showProduct4 = document.getElementById("mk-prod04");
        showProduct3 = document.getElementById("mk-prod03");
        showProduct4.style.display = "inline";
        showProduct3.style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (oProdId === "mk-prod03") {
        hideProduct6 = document.getElementById("mk-prod06");
        hideProduct5 = document.getElementById("mk-prod05");
        hideProduct4 = document.getElementById("mk-prod04");
        hideProduct6.style.display = "none";
        hideProduct5.style.display = "none";
        hideProduct4.style.display = "none";
        showProduct3 = document.getElementById("mk-prod03");
        showProduct3.style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (oProdId === "mk-prod02") {
        hideProduct6 = document.getElementById("mk-prod06");
        hideProduct5 = document.getElementById("mk-prod05");
        hideProduct4 = document.getElementById("mk-prod04");
        hideProduct3 = document.getElementById("mk-prod03");
        hideProduct6.style.display = "none";
        hideProduct5.style.display = "none";
        hideProduct4.style.display = "none";
        hideProduct3.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `class` for all the elements,then inside your function , hide all the elements with that `class` , use the id and set only the element with that `id` to `display = 'inline'`

Comment: See [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you basically have written out a loop. And it's quite trivial to formulate that loop explicitly:

```
function myId() {
    adjustStyle();
    var x = // the number, wherever you got it from. Maybe:
            // parseInt(oProdId.slice(7), 10)
    for (var i=6; i>2; i--) {
        var product = document.getElementById("mk-prod"+("0"+i).slice(-2));
        product.style.display = i > x ? "none" : "inline";
    }
}
```

Comment: The deeper problem is using ids like this... or using ids at all in fact

Comment: @Esailija: Why? He needs to distinguish and explictly select the elements.

Comment: @Esailija: Of course, you could use CSS like `div.mk-prod { display: none } div.mk-prod.active, div.mk-prod.active ~ div.mk-prod { display: inline; }`, but you still had to select that div to set the class `active` on it somehow.

Comment: No, you can just use the reference to the element that you inevitably have.

Comment: @Esailija: But that depends on the use case, like in an event handler. Does the OP have one? We don't know. But I agree, there are often better options than numbered ids.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly when I placed it on the main code.
The line bellow is awesome:
product.style.display = i > x ? "none" : "inline";

Comment: Could you guys recommend a book for beginners? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function hideShow(id) {
    var upTo = id.match(/md-prod0(\d)/)[1];

    for (var i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById('md-prod0' + i); 
        if (i <= upTo) element.style.display = 'inline';
        else element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

You have to adjust it slightly if more elements will be added.

Basically it loops over `3` to `6` and checks whether the current element is less than or equal to the given ID. In that case it shows the element. Otherwise it hides it.